# Chainlink node can't make requests to Chainlink external adapter (on localhost)

Tags: docker, chainlink

I have a chainlink Node which is running on port 6688. I'm running it with docker, with the following command:

```
cd ~/.chainlink-rinkeby && docker run -p 6688:6688  \
-v ~/.chainlink-rinkeby:/chainlink  \
-it --env-file=.env \
 smartcontract/chainlink:1.4.0-root local n -p /chainlink/.password -a /chainlink/.api
```

And I have an external adapter running on port 8080.

If I request it `{ "id": 0, "data":{ "columns": ["blood","heath"], "linesAmount":500 } }` it returns me a correct payload, in the format that is expected from the external adapter:

```
{
    "jobRunID": 0,
    "data": {
        "ipfsHash": "anIpfshashShouldBeHere",
        "providers": [
            "0x03996eF07f84fEEe9f1dc18B255A8c01A4986701"
        ],
        "result": "anIpfshashShouldBeHere"
    },
    "result": "anIpfshashShouldBeHere",
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

The problem is, in the chainlink node, specifically in the `fetch` method it gives me an error:
`error making http request: Post "http://localhost:8080": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused`

Is it related to the docker container? I don't see why it wouldn't be able to request resuources from another port in the same machine. Am I missing some configuration maybe?
From what I've read from the docs it's possible to run the adapter locally.
Below, a picture with more information:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're External Adapter (EA) is running on `http://localhost:8080` and you're trying to reach that EA from a Chainlink node running inside Docker, then you can't use `localhost`, you need to get out of the Docker container and onto the host running the Docker engine (your Windows or Mac machine).

To do, so define your bridge to use `http://host.docker.internal:8080`.

Further details can be found in the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/).

Comment: On linux I just had to use 172.17.0.1 and it also worked.